# Ceiling fan wiring issues

Tags: wiring

I have a light that I was going to change to a ceiling fan with light. There seems to be a white and black coming in that is hot no matter what position I flip the switch. There's also a red, blue with white stripes and a black that doesn't have any power at all. I've tried several different combinations but I could only get the fan power if I ran it to the black and white that's always hot.I'd love to use the switch but can't figure it out. Please help

Comment: Add location to your question and pictures.  In North America having both black and white hot usually means a 240 volt setup(not good for a 120v fan).  Are the red, blue, and the other black also in the junction box or from the fan?

Comment: Can you post the pictures you took before you disconnected the existing light?  :-)

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: What are the colors at the switch, this sounds like a common switch leg where the black/ white is the feeder from the service panel and the red, blue, white, black was a future set up so the fan and light could be on separate circuits, is this in conduit? I ask because white with blue is an way to identify the neutral in a 3 phase system ( or white with a black / white with a red is used in some facilities like condo’s and light commercial so you can identify the circuit).